# How can props be used if not specified in the parameters of a function

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Why is props here when normally it is to be specified in a function's parameters

```
props.onSubmit({
        id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
     })

  };

  return (
    <form  onSubmit= {handleSubmit}  className="todo-form">
```

This code is to create a unique id for each input element.

Full code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ToDoForm() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit= e =>{
    e.preventDefault();

     props.onSubmit({
        id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
     })

  };

  return (
    <form  onSubmit= {handleSubmit}  className="todo-form">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add a todo"
        value={input}
        name="text"
        className="todo-input"
      />
      <button className='todo-button'>Add todo</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ToDoForm;
```

Video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1E08i2UJGI&t=346s

Timestamp
11:46

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Sorry, later in the video he fixed the error at
12:22

Comment: What is the time stamp? Please respond by editing the answer, not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).